# To show values in Jlist from DataBase onload

Tags: java, database, swing, jlist

[To show values in Jlist from DataBase onload][Swing GUI and Database`

Initializing the code:

```
 public void initMethod()
    {


         try {
             PortSelectionBox.addItem("COM1");
             PortSelectionBox.addItem("COM2");

             String[] listData={"sac : 1", "prl : 2","railway : 3", "railway : 4", "railway : 5", "prl : 6"};
             //SourceJList.setListData(listData);


             //get values from database and show in destlist
             String query="Select * from `test`.`mapgroup`;";
             System.out.println("query for selecttion: "+query);
             ResultSet rs= con.SelectData(query);
             ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
             while(rs.next())
             {
                 group=rs.getString("GroupName");
                 port=rs.getString("PortId");
                 System.out.println("grp: "+group);
                 System.out.println("port: "+port);
                 al.add(group);

             }

             //check if values present in db then show in dest list

             //check which port is selected and then show value from database



             if((PortSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString()).equals(port))
             {
                 System.out.println("if condition satisfied"); 
             }
              for (String string : listData) {
                 SorceModel.addElement(string);
             }
             SourceJList.setModel(SorceModel);


         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }
```

action performed on combobox onchnage:

```
 private void PortSelectionBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //Show values in destList according to values stored in DB with there ports ,what to do here to map values with values stored in db



    }
```

action performed on add(>>) button on click:

```
private void addBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {            

         try {

            String port=PortSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
             String group=SourceJList.getSelectedValue().toString();
             String temp=group;
             String query="query to insert into db";
             con.Ins_Upd_Del(query);
             System.out.println("code to add: "+query);

             System.out.println("data added");

            DestModel.addElement(temp);
            DestJList.setModel(DestModel);
            SorceModel.removeElement(group);
            System.out.println("done....");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }
```

,

action performed on remove(<<) button onclick:

```
private void removeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        String port=PortSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
         String group=DestJList.getSelectedValue().toString();
         String temp=group;
         String query="query to delet";
         System.out.println("code to remove: "+query);
         con.Ins_Upd_Del(query);
         System.out.println("data added");

        SorceModel.addElement(temp);
        SourceJList.setModel(SorceModel);
        DestModel.removeElement(group);
        System.out.println("done....");
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(PanelSMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

I have done the work for add and remove buttons. but now i am stuck in the view part.
What i am doing is that i am populating first Jlist from an arraylist. when i add any element from this jlist its get added into second JList and inserted into DB, similarly on remove operation it is doing the reverse.

now what i need is, those values which i have already added in second Jlist ,it should not be shown in first Jlist and vice versa on the time of load and values should be shown respectively according to the selection. also the selection box plays an important role here as i want to show the values in the jlist according to the selected value.

For example if i have stored com1 with "prl : 1" then it should be shown only in second Jlist onload.
Incase i want to update this lists then it should be done in DB and displayed likewise.

i am not getting the flow for the view part. 
i already have everything stored in DB, i just want to map the things and show them accordingly .

Please help me out... as i am not able to get what to do next...
`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9tgO.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the initialization of the two `JList` components to work properly. The destination list should be filled based on the database, right? This could work like this (part of the `initMethod` method):

```
// [...]

//get values from database and show in destlist
String query="Select * from `test`.`mapgroup`;";
System.out.println("query for selection: "+query);
ResultSet rs= con.SelectData(query);
String port = null;
ArrayList<String> groupsInDatabase = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next())
{
    String group=rs.getString("GroupName");
    port=rs.getString("PortId");
    System.out.println("grp: "+group);
    System.out.println("port: "+port);
    groupsInDatabase.add(group);
}

//check if values present in db then show in dest list
DestModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (final String group : groupsInDatabase) {
    DestModel.addElement(group);
}
DestJList.setModel(DestModel);

// [...]
```

Should the source list be filled with everything from the `listData` variable, except groups that are in the database? (I have renamed the `listData` variable to `allGroups` below.) Initialization for this list could look like this (also part of the `initMethod` method):

```
// [...]

SourceModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (String group : allGroups) {
    if (!groupsInDatabase.contains(group)) {
        SourceModel.addElement(group);
    }
}
SourceJList.setModel(SourceModel);

// [...]
```

The role of the `PortSelectionBox` is not yet clear to me. Do "COM1" and "COM2" relate to certain records in the database (like "prl : 1" and "prl : 2")?

Comment: Actually for the 1st time nothing is present in the DB so the destList should be empty. The PortSelectionBOX is imp because first i am selecting the port to which i want to add the groups, once i add something to it, it should be added in the destList and removed from the sourcelist. Now when next time open the GUI, i should get the result as stored in the DB corresponding to particular selected port. exm : i store port COM1 with prl:1 & prl:2, then i select COM2 & store railway:1 and railway:2, now all these values should be displayed to DestList with there corresponding ports. Thanks

Comment: i have a table in DB called mapgroup having columns mapgroupID,GroupName and PortName. i am adding the data on add button event in DB, now  if i have the values COM1 with prl:1 & prl:2, then i select COM2 & store railway:1 and railway:2 stored in DB, then in view part ,groups should be displayed in destList with there respective ports.  i cant understand where to write this code like in initilization or in selectionBox onchange event, also how to map these groups with there ports to show in the destList

Comment: Also the PortSelectionBox is dynamic,(Just for example purpose  i have added the values manually in the selectionbox) ,so any no of values can be there and i can map any port to any group... i just want to see the respective data according to port selected in the destList(values are fetched from dataBase)

Comment: When are the group-port mapping stored in the database? When the user presses the Continue button or also when the user selects a different port? Should the groups in the destination list store for which port they have been added or should all destination groups be linked to the currently selected port? It would be a good idea to update the code in your question and explain your remaining issue that is related to the question ("To show values in Jlist from DataBase onload"). An example always helps.

Comment: no problem i solved the issue, it was just a silly mistake i was doing. what i did is , on selection of the port i cleared the destList and destModel and then fetched the data accordingly.

Comment: Code  to write inside portselectionbox:  ` String SelectedPort = PortSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println("getselitem: "+SelectedPort);
        if(SelectedPort.equals(port))
             {
          
                String query="Select * from `tablename` where PortID='"+SelectedPort+"'";
                ResultSet rs = con.SelectData(query);
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    String gn = rs.getString("GroupName");
                    DestModel.addElement(gn);
                }
          
             }`